# Listen to click event on an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, iframe

I'm trying to detect when a user clicks on a Facebook like button.
What I've tried:

```
$('iframe').click(function() {alert('clicked!');};
$('#wrapper').click(function() {alert('clicked!');};
```

where `#wrapper` is a div around the iframe. The second one works only if I click inside the wrapper in an area outside the iframe.

Another approach is to lay a div on top of the iframe, but then the like button will not be clickable anymore...
Is there a way to receive this click event without preventing the event to proceed into the iframe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for your particular case of facebook, there are [events you can subscribe](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/?_fb_noscript=1) to

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (targetUrl) {
        alert('liked');
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function (targetUrl) {
        alert('unliked');
    });
};
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. So it's just possible because of facebook's API, but not in general, right?

Comment: @Cedric, right. You can't access the `document` of an iframe if that iframe points to another "origin". See "same origin policy".